# android phone which connects to web application

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm creating a photo capturing system by using javascript and also HTML5 for my college project. I'm thinking of creating "somehow" called a remote control by using android device to communicate to the web application open on my laptop.

maybe I make you guys confuse already,

let say the android device have a CAPTURE BUTTON. when user click on the button, it will capture the photo inside the laptop web applications. The purpose of the android device is work like a remote control when user tap on the CAPTURE BUTTON. Is there any technology can make this happen?

I have this idea is because of there's a lot of android apps which is can connects to the computer as a mouse or as a keyboard. So, I was thinking is it possible that create a application communicate with the javascript inside of my webapp.

Thank you for answering and viewing the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @323go Thanks, will take note on that.

Comment: Web Sockets might work for you, I use them to use my Android phone to control my computer. The rough idea is my phone sends a message to my PHP server, then the server sends the message to my computer application.

Comment: @TomHart alright, I'll study what is that for more details. Thanks BTW. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible. You can do it by using `Node.js`. I have created a presentation using `Node.js` and by using html code. Then I open the controller on laptop and ppt on my mobile application `WebView`. then I am able to record and save the video automatic as slides changes in my android phone.

so by manipulating some code you can do what ever you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will research on this for further details.

Comment: you can check this link this is what you want [LINK](http://colorlabsproject.com/tutorials/create-awesome-presentation-with-reveal-js-and-nodejs/)

Comment: yeah, this is almost the same as what I ask. Thanks!